Hubspot sub domain redirect to main website page
What is the best way to redirect a sub domain page created in Hub Spot, to a page created on the main website:
Redirect a Hub Spot subdomain page:
https://sub.businessname.co.uk/pagename
To this page:
https://www.businessname.co.uk/name/pagename
Thanks
I tried:
# Redirect HubSpot subdomain page to main site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.businessname\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pagename2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.businessname.co.uk/name/pagename/ [R=301,L]


That redirection rule should do what you phrase, apart from the "2" in the second condition which is a typo, I assume. You don't actually need that second condition: RewriteRule ^/?pagename/?$ https://www.businessname.co.uk/name/pagename/ [R=301,L].
